# create-react-app - where to put images for a srcSet?

Tags: create-react-app

I'm running `json-server` with a `create-react-app` application. Within the db.json file I have mock data:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": {
            "src": "./images/test-480w.jpeg",
            "srcSet": "./images/test-480w.jpeg 480w, ./images/test-800w.jpeg 800w",
            "sizes": "(max-width: 600px) 480px, 800px"
          }
        }
      }],
...
```

Within a React component I have:

```
...
<img src={data[0].image.src} sizes={data[0].image.sizes} srcSet={data[0].image.srcSet} />
...
```

But not sure where to put the images in the folder structure. Tried in the root and in `public`, but nothing is working.